# How to fill an array of objects with the rest of missing months (12 months in total)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

To show a monthly report of balance, I receive this kind of response from the backend, starting only from the month when the user was registered on the website.

```
[{name: "April", balance: "40.00"}, {name: "May", balance: "27.00"}]
```

I want to show a graph for the balance of the user from 1 year till the last element of the array received when other months from 1 year are missing.

So I would like my converted array to be like below

```
 reports = [
    { name: 'June', balance: '0' },
    { name: 'July', balance: '0' },
    { name: 'August', balance: '0' },
    [...allOtherMonthtsBetween],
    { name: 'April', balance: '40.00' },
    { name: 'May', balance: '27.00' },
  ];
```

How can I achieve this?

If this helps, here in array holding number values of every month

```
 const months = {
    January: '01',
    February: '02',
    March: '03',
    April: '04',
    May: '05',
    June: '06',
    July: '07',
    August: '08',
    September: '09',
    October: '10',
    November: '11',
    December: '12',
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've interpreted the question to mean that you want to back fill months prior to the first available month, that the months in the given data won't have gaps and that you need at least 12 months in total.

```js
const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
const data = [{name: "April", balance: "40.00"}, {name: "May", balance: "27.00"}];

const back_fill_months = (data) => {
  const last_month_index = months.indexOf(data[data.length - 1].name);

  return Array
    .from(
      { length: Math.max(12 - data.length, 0) },
      (v, i) => (last_month_index + i + 1) % 12
    )
    .map((month_index) => ({ name: months[month_index], balance: "0.00" }))
    .concat(data);
};

console.log( back_fill_months(data) );
```

Comment: correct, thanks. it completely fulfills what i needed

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```js
const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

const data = [
    {name: "April", balance: "40.00"},
    {name: "May", balance: "27.00"},
    {name: "August", balance: "27.00"},
    {name: "February", balance: "27.00"}
];

const startingMonth = monthNames.indexOf(data[0].name);
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const month = monthNames[(i + startingMonth) % 12];
    const dataOfMonthIndex = data.findIndex((d) => d.name === month);
    
    if (dataOfMonthIndex < 0) {
        data.splice(i, 0, { name: month, balance: 0 })
    }
}

console.log(data);
```